# Listen for query at chats/*************/messages failed: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I wrote a firebase rule to allow read only if `uid` is in user array of parent collection.

When I try to query collection to get list of document, I get the error

```
> Listen for query at chats/**************/messages failed:
> Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Here is security rule I user for collection:

```
match /chat/{chat_id}/messages/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chat/$(chat_id)).data.users;
      allow delete, update: if false;
    }
```

Is it that my security rule is wrong or a query cannot be performed on collection with such rule?.

Comment: Could you provide the code for your request?

Comment: @kingkong.js thanks for the help. After long time of debugging, I found out name of collection was chats and not chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki:

Firestore Security Rules should be matched by the correct collection name as @Anga mentioned by correcting the collection name should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that `users` is an array of uid's (strings) like:

```
users = ["uid1", "uid2", "uid3"]
```

You could also try storing the users as a dictionary:

```
users = {uid1: ..., uid2: ... , uid3: ...}
```

And access it the following way:

```
 allow read, write: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chat/$(chat_id)).data.users[reqeust.auth.uid] != null
```

Comment: thanks for the help. After long time of debugging, I found out name of collection was chats and not chat